# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' error while using vector

Tags: c++, vector, error-handling, runtime-error, outofrangeexception

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int count=0;
int checkDivisor(int d,int*ptr){
    vector<int> v;
    int temp=0;
for (int i = *ptr; ; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1; j<=i; j++)
   {
       if(i%j==0){
           v.push_back(j);
           count++;
       }
   }
   if (count>=4)
   {
       temp=i;
      break;
   }
   else
   {
       v.clear();
   }
}
for(int k=0;k<v.size();k++){
    if ((v.at(k+1)-v.at(k))<=d)
    {
       return 0;
    }
}
return temp;
}

int main(){
int t;
cin>>t;
while (t>0)
{   
    int d;
    cin>>d;
    int value=0;
    int*point=&value;
    int result=checkDivisor(d,point);
    if(result==0){
        *point++;
        checkDivisor(d,point);
    }
    else{
    cout<<checkDivisor(d,point)<<endl;
    }
    t--;
}
return 0;
}
```

This returns an error terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1).
**What I am trying to do is return a number if it has more than 3 divisors and the difference between any two divisors is greater than d**
Please help.

Comment: `k` goes up to `size -1` and you're trying to access `k+1` which is out of bounds of the vector

Answer (score 0):

The `std::vector::at` does a range check. The error occurs in your `for (k=0; k < v.size(); ++k)` loop, where you try to access `v.at(k+1)`. This is out of bounds when `k=v.size()-1`. Also, is there any reason why you pass the `ptr` as pointer? I'd recommend to pass by value. You also have several problems with your logic. Here is an example that works (for **positive** numbers):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<limits>
std::vector<int> try_get_first_n_divisors(const int number, const int n)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= number; divisor++)
    {
        // check if it is a divisor of number
        if(number%divisor==0)
        {
            // is so, add it to the vector
            v.push_back(divisor);

            // When we found more than four divisors, leave the loop
            if(v.size() == 4)
                break;
        }  
    }
    return v;
}

bool check_divisor_dist_cirterion(int d, int number){

    std::vector<int> v = try_get_first_n_divisors(number, 4);
    
    if (v.size() < 4)
        return false;
    else
    {
        // check the distance between divisors
        for(int k=1; k<v.size(); ++k){
            if ((v.at(k)-v.at(k-1)) <= d)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(){ 

    int d;
    std::cin>>d;
    int number = 4;
    while(!check_divisor_dist_cirterion(d, number) 
        && (number < std::numeric_limits<int>::max()))
    {
        ++number;
    }
    
    std::cout << "found " << number << " with divisors ";
    for (auto divisor : try_get_first_n_divisors(number, 4))
        std::cout << "  " << divisor;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cs9qWo)

Note that the number you pass to check the criterion is a divisor too. If you want to change this, then you have to use `<` comparison in  `try_get_first_n_divisors`: `for (int divisor = 1; divisor < number; divisor++)`.

Also, this example is not optimized. For example, if the distance > 1 then you can skip even numbers as `1, 2` will always be divisors and thus violating your criterion.

**Note** I haven't checked the logic for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This code `if ((v.at(k+1)-v.at(k))<=d)` gets the number at index `k+1`. But when `k` equals `v.size()-1` `k+1` equals `v.size()` so this is an out of range error.

Now this has been pointed out I'm sure its obvious to you. You should develop the ability to look at your own code and understand what it does, especially when the error message is telling you exactly what you've done wrong.

Presumably this code

```
for(int k=0;k<v.size();k++){
```

should be this

```
for(int k=0;k<v.size()-1;k++){
```